# Textinput result into a SQL search in Bokeh

Tags: python, sql, mysql, bokeh, textinput

I have been doing a dashboard in bokeh (and flask) with the MySQL db that I created with my collection of music. The idea is to create a query with a parameter from the user, having a dataframe with the result and showing it after within a plot. My problem is how to get the result of the textinput into the query, like this:

```
query = f'SELECT * FROM `tracks_per_year` WHERE tracktitle LIKE "{text_input_value}"'

track_search_df = dbconnect.run_query_to_df(query, connection=cnx)
```

The documentation of bokeh is a bit poor (in my opinion) regarding this issue, showing only how to build the textinput and showing what you have typed, but not how to retrieve it (unless I am missing something, which can also be the case).

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, TextInput

text_input = TextInput(value="default", title="Label:")
text_input.js_on_change("value", CustomJS(code="""
    console.log('text_input: value=' + this.value, this.toString())
"""))

show(text_input)
```

Comment: If you want to use the `value` in real Python code callbacks, then you will have to create a Bokeh server app, for which the docs are extensive https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html If you generate standalone HTML output (i.e. with `show`) then only JavaScript callbacks are possible (naturally, because browsers cannot run Python code)

Comment: I was afraid that would be the only possible way. Anyway, thank you for the clarification. But even with JS callbacks, are they isolated from the python code? There is no communication between them, despite being different languages?